# Upgrade TFS2018 to Devops2020 on premise issue

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to upgrade TFS2018 to Devops2020.  I ran the Devops2020.exe and it appears to have upgraded my TFS-Configuration db because Devops2020 recognizes it and the collection is started.  It did not seem to appear to upgrade my other two collections.  I cannot start either collection. I get the following error:

`The host cannot be started.  the servicing needs to be scheduled and completed before the host can be started.`

[image]

My databases still have the TFS_prefix on the db's in SQL server how ever I created a Test collection and the db is prefixed with AzureDevOps_.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you lost the data from database.

The best suggestion is that you should restore the database from the backup. And TFS usually has the backup when using tfs or before tfs upgrade.

Try the following:

1. [Unconfigure the TFSfeature](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-devops/unconfigure-team-foundation-server/ba-p/697860).

Also, You could use the "Remove feature" option in Administration console to remove feature or use the `TfsConfig setup / uninstall：All`.

2. [Restore the database from the backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-restore-dbs?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#to-restore-databases).
3. Configure the TFS again in Administration Console.

**Besides**, you could also enter **TFS Administration Console** -> **the target collection** -> **Status tab**.   Find those jobs that are failed, try to click the **Rerun Job** button and check the result.